# Transform javascript array with objects with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm wondering what the best way would be to transform my javascript array with objects. I have tried making a fancy chain with lodash but I can't figure it out.

I need to format the data this way because of the way the backend works.

```
// from:
var something = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    stuff: [
      {
        id: 1
      },
      {
        id: 2
      },
      {
        id: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    stuff: []
  },
  {
    name: 'baz',
    stuff: [
      {
        id: 7
      },
      {
        id: 8
      }
    ]
  }
];

// to:
var transformed = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    included: {
      included: [1, 2, 3]
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    included: {
      included: []
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'baz',
    included: {
      included: [7, 8]
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: You really need to have added the code you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this quite concisely with two [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls (the array built in or lodash's map), one nested to handle the `"included"` array within each object:

```
const transformed = something.map(it => {
  return {
    name: it.name,
    included: {
      included: it.stuff.map(thing => thing.id)
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `lodash`, just use the [`Array.prototype.map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
// Sorry no fancy ES6 => here :S
var res = something.map(function(item) {
  item.included = {included : item.stuff.map(function(i) {return i.id})}
  delete(item.stuff)
  return item
})
```

Per *@ssube*'s comment:

```
var res = something.map(function(item) {
  return {
    included : {included : item.stuff.map(function(i) {return i.id})},
    name: item.name
  }
})
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/esavpwjw/)

Comment: This is going to mutate the original objects, which `map` should not do ([see this output](https://jsfiddle.net/esavpwjw/1/)). Rather than modifying and returning `item`, you probably want to return a new object with the right properties.